# Material Table Paginator Displaying All Data on a Giant Page Instead of Dividing into Pages

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using the Material Table with a Paginator according to [the example found here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) (view the example called `Data table with sorting, pagination, and filtering`). However, it's not actually dividing my data into pages. The paginator gets populated with the right number I set, but it still shows all of the data on one page.

Strangely, I had it working so I committed my code and then checked again, with no changes, and it stopped working.

Template:

```
<h1>Pokémon List</h1>
<div class="loading" *ngIf="isLoading">Loading...</div>
<div class="error" *ngIf="isError">Error loading Pokémon.</div>
<div class="container" *ngIf="!isLoading && !isError">

    <form class="parameter-form">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Generation</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(value)]="selectedGenNumber" (selectionChange)="loadPokemon()">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let gen of generations" [value]="gen.id">
                    {{gen.name}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Site</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(value)]="selectedSite">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let site of availableSites;" [value]="site.name">
                    {{site.name}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>

    <form class="search-form">
        <mat-form-field class="search-field">
            <mat-label>Name or Number</mat-label>
            <input name="search" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Name or Number" #input matInput
                type="search" autofocus />
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="pokemonDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="image">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"><img width="50" height="50"
                    [src]="'https://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/'+pokemon.name+'.jpg'" /></td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Number </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> {{pokemon.number}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> {{pokemon.displayName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="evolution-link">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Evolution </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> <a mat-raised-button color="primary" target="_blank"
                    [href]="pokemon.evolutionUrls[selectedSite]">Evolution</a></td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="location-link">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> <a mat-raised-button [href]="pokemon.locationUrls[selectedSite]"
                    target="_blank" color="accent">Location</a>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="effectiveness-link">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Effectiveness </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> <a mat-raised-button
                    [href]="pokemon.effectivenessUrls[selectedSite]" target="_blank" color="warn">Effectiveness</a>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="learnset-link">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Moveset </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pokemon"> <a mat-raised-button [href]="pokemon.learnsetUrls[selectedSite]"
                    target="_blank" color="primary">Learnset</a>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [length]="selectedGeneration.pokemonCount" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[10,20, 50, 100]"
        showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Pokemon } from 'src/Pokemon';
import { PokeApiService } from 'src/app/poke-api.service';
import { TextFormat } from 'src/app/TextFormat';
import { Sites } from 'src/app/Sites';
import { Site } from 'src/app/Site';
import { TemplateKeywords } from 'src/app/TemplateKeywords';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { Generation } from '../Generation';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-pokemon-list',
    templateUrl: './pokemon-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./pokemon-list.component.css']
})
export class PokemonListComponent implements OnInit {
    pokemon: Pokemon[] = [];
    columnsToDisplay: string[] = ["image", "number", "name", "evolution-link", "location-link", "effectiveness-link", "learnset-link"];
    searchText: string = '';
    isLoading: boolean;
    isError: boolean = false;

    availableSites: Site[]; //DATA WILL GO HERE
    currentGen: number = 8;
    generationNumbers: number[] = Array(this.currentGen);
    generations: Generation[] =
        [new Generation(1, 151),
        new Generation(2, 251),
        new Generation(3, 386),
        new Generation(4, 493),
        new Generation(5, 649),
        new Generation(6, 721),
        new Generation(7, 807),
        new Generation(8, 893)];

    pokemonDataSource: MatTableDataSource<Pokemon> = new MatTableDataSource();
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

    selectedSite: string = "SITE HERE"; //TODO: change this to be a parameter
    selectedGenNumber: number = 8;
    selectedGeneration: Generation;

    constructor(private pokeApiService: PokeApiService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadPokemon();
    }

    loadPokemon() {
        console.log("hello");
        this.selectedGeneration = this.getGenerationForNumber(this.selectedGenNumber);
        if (this.selectedGeneration) {
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.pokeApiService.getAllPokemon(this.selectedGeneration.pokemonCount).then((response) => {
                let data = response;
                console.log("this right here", data);
                const pokemon = data.map(p => {
                    return {
                        name: p.name,
                        displayName: TextFormat.ToTitleCase(p.name),
                        number: p.number,
                        evolutionUrls: this.buildEvolutionUrls(p.name, p.number),
                        locationUrls: this.buildLocationUrls(p.name, p.number),
                        effectivenessUrls: this.buildEffectivenessUrls(p.name, p.number),
                        learnsetUrls: this.buildLearnsetUrls(p.name, p.number)
                    } as Pokemon;
                });
                this.pokemonDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(pokemon);
                this.pokemonDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                this.pokemonDataSource.sort = this.sort;
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
        }
        else {
            this.isError = true;
        }
    }

    applyFilter(event: Event) {
        const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        this.pokemonDataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

        if (this.pokemonDataSource.paginator) {
            this.pokemonDataSource.paginator.firstPage();
        }
    }

    getGenerationForNumber(genNumber: number) {
        console.log("gen", genNumber);
        return this.generations.find(g => g.id == genNumber);
    }
//trimmed off some functions referenced above to keep this simpler, they're just utility functions
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that, at first your table is hidden, so, when you make `this.pokemonDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` you has no yet the dataSource. I think you can resolve giving Angular a breath, that's: using setTimeout

```
this.pokeApiService.getAllPokemon(this.selectedGeneration.pokemonCount).then(
    ....
    //first "isLoading=false"
    this.isLoading = false;
    //create the dataSource and paginator enclosed in a setTimeout
    setTimeout(()=>{
         this.pokemonDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(pokemon);
         this.pokemonDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
         this.pokemonDataSource.sort = this.sort;
    })
)
```

BTW, Is there any reason to use Promise over Observables?

Comment: I'm new to Angular so I went for what I knew from using Vue. It seems like Observables might make my life easier?

Comment: Yeah this was why it was happening. I ended up removing the *ngIf for showing it, but it does seem like there should be a way to do this without a timeout since you never know how long the call might take to resolve I guess.

Comment: No, a setTimeout only say to Angular: after you repaint all using "isLoading=false", return and remember that you need execute this anothers instructions and repaint again. It's not for wait to finish the call. (see that we don't use miliseconds)The call is finished yet -we are writting code inside the function subscribe-.